# Python Get variable output to another variable with specified string

Tags: python, python-2.7

variable1 has:

```
 Server: Server1
 Power State: Faulty
 Power load: 120
 CPU State: Critical
 CPU Usage: 97%
 Mem State: Normal
 Mem Usage: 10%
```

I want `variable2 = Critical`
That is cpu state output and any value  next to cpu state.

I do not want to print to file and grep it.

variable1 output is get from command output

Comment: Is `variable1` a dictionary? A class instance? Something else? Do you have some code that demonstrates how `variable1` is created?

Comment: Variable1 is not dictionary ..variable1 output is from command output

Comment: Surely you'll manage to split this string into lines, then split each line at the colon `:` and find the line that starts with "CPU State"?

Comment: Yes i need,  CPU State: Critical

Answer (score 0):

Considering variable1 is string data-type

```
variable1 = " Server: Server1\n\
 Power State: Faulty\n\
 Power load: 120\n\
 CPU State: Critical\n\
 CPU Usage: 97%\n\
 Mem State: Normal\n\
 Mem Usage: 10%"
print variable1

match = re.search("CPU State:(.+)",variable1)
if(match):
        variable2 = match.group(1).strip()
        print variable2
else:   
        print "match not find"
```

Comment: Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: can you please print type(variable1) If it is not string it will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can split every line by **:** and put the key, value to a dictionary.
Instead of just extracting the variable you require, why not store all the values in a dictionary. You will be able to access any value by key.

```
def extract_values(string):
    string = string.strip()
    data = {}
    lines = string.split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        key, value = line.split(":")
        data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    return data

string = """
    Server: Server1
    Power State: Faulty
    Power load: 120
    CPU State: Critical
    CPU Usage: 97%
    Mem State: Normal
    Mem Usage: 10%
"""

data = extract_values(string)
print(data)
variable2 = data['CPU State']
```

The **data** will be:

```
>>> data
{'Power load': '120', 'Power State': 'Faulty', 'CPU Usage': '97%', 'Mem State': 'Normal', 'CPU State': 'Critical', 'Mem Usage': '10%', 'Server': 'Server1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

supposing that variable1 is a string, the most basic and non-dynamic approach is

```
lines = variable1.splitlines()  # returns a list containing lines of variable1
for line in lines:
    if "CPU State" in line:
        # split the string by : and get the second item in list
        # and strip it to avoid any unwanted spaces before or after it
        variable2 = line.split(":")[1].strip()
print variable2
```

and the output will be

```
Critical
```